# unstruct wikipedia synonym bracket

Tags: python, regex

I want to unstruct wikipedia synonym bracket.

Here's a easy one to do.

```
He is [[Korean]].
```

I can remove bracket.

Here's another difficult one.

```
He lives in [[Gimhae city|Gimhae]].
```

The first one(Gimhae city) is wikipedia document title.

So I have to get second one in bracket.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I want to get second one in bracket. "He lives in Gimhae." is what i want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\[{2}(?:[^|\]]*\|)?([^]]*)]{2}
```

And relace with `\1`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fK9eQ1/3)

Here is what the regex matches:

- `\[{2}` - 2 opening square brackets
- `(?:[^|\]]*\|)?` - 0 or 1 sequence of characters other than `|` and `]` (with `[^|\]]*`) and a literal `|` with `\|` (note it is escaped outside of character class)
- `([^]]*)` - matches and captures into Group 1 that we'll reference later with `\1` 0 or more characters other than a closing square bracket
- `]{2}` - 2 closing square brackets (note we do not have to escape them here since the first `[` was escaped).

The [Python snippet](http://ideone.com/nr1l6D):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\[{2}(?:[^|\]]*\|)?([^]]*)]{2}')
test_str = "He lives in [[Gimhae city|Gimhae]]. He lives in [[Gimhae]]. "
result = re.sub(p, r"\1", test_str)
print(result) # => He lives in Gimhae. He lives in Gimhae.
```

Comment: I've edit a little. It can be used for multiple brackets in one sentence.
p = re.compile(r'\\[{2}(?:[^|\\]]*\|)?([^]]*)]{2}')